# PTR vs NAPTR Whats the difference?

Tags: email, pointers, dns

I am setting a mailserver and one of instructions tells me to set a PTR record for my ip, i went to my DNS manager and the closest i could find is NAPTR. If i set a NAPTR record, is it (in my case) equivalent of setting PTR record? What is the difference between those two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, those two are not equivalent in any way.**

Their only similarity is in name.

..

**PTR record**

PTR record is like a reversed A record. It's used for reverse DNS lookup.
Using the IP you can get the hostname/s associated to it.

More info [here](https://www.siteground.com/kb/what_is_a_ptr_record_and_how_to_add_one/)

..

**NAPTR record**

NAPTR records are commonly used with SIP in conjunction with SRV records to discover what types of service are available for a name. Basically (and not exactly correctly) One could say NAPTR is a way to say publicly what protocols does a certain domain implement. If for example you can make a VoIP call to example.com, or rather try email.

More info [here](https://anders.com/cms/264/)

Comment: So how did you set the PTR record if the DNS manager didn't give you the option to do so?

Comment: I had to set it up in my VPS's control panel. Not really sure how it was called, but it had something to do with "DNS reverse lookup" or just "DNS lookup". I discovered it accidentally out of desperacy.